# How can I have the return string of a program appear in my tcsh prompt?

Tags: prompt, tcsh

I am using vcprompt to provide me with the git branch and dirtiness status. It returns it as a string.

How can I catch this string in my tcsh prompt setting? I guess I need to put the call to vcprompt somehow in the prompt definition, but I can't find the syntax for that.

Edit:
Solution is:

```
alias precmd "echo -n `vcprompt`"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original C shell, you could simply embed command substitution directly into the `prompt` variable, which I always thought made more sense.  Under tcsh, you have to set up the `precmd` alias to do it.  I'm not familiar with `vcprompt` but I assume it generates a newline at the end, so you'll probably want to use `echo -n` to throw away that newline, putting the prompt on the same line as the command, not the line before.  Set `prompt` to whatever you want following; here I'm assuming you'll want a space.

```
alias precmd echo -n `vcprompt`
set prompt = ' '
```

Comment: Almost. Had to put quotes around everything after precmd. (And there seems to be no frickin' way to write that command line in a comment here without some markup happening... :(